# Any way to disable the force touch detection for my Apple WatchKit 2 app

Tags: watchkit, force-touch

Whenever I press somewhat hard on my Apple WatchKit 2 app the view compresses as it attempts to detect a force touch.  Is there any way to disable this?  This additional detection is affecting the accuracy of it handling the numerous other buttons I have on the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to disable the force touch attempt at this time. Even Apple's own watch apps that don't have menus still show the force touch "bouce" effect if there is no menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with SpriteKit, that can adjust anything.  Also apples Phone Dialer app has force touch bounce disaled.